# I need to know the flow of this program?can anyone help me with this?

Tags: javascript

This is the JavaScript code.

```
function loadProfiles(usernames){
    if(usernames.length>3){
        var wmsg='This might take a while';
    }
    else{
        var imsg="Just a sec";
    }
    console.log(imsg);
}
loadProfiles(['Dinesh','Saratha','Sundhararasu']);
```

when i try to console `wmsg` it gives `undefined`

when i try to console `imsg` it gives `just a sec` but expected output is `undefined`.

what is the reason?

Comment: because it is undefined. because length is **NOT** > 3 - the length of your array is **THREE** ... a number can not be greater than itself (there's something almost spiritual in that statement) - note: why are you using two different variables to hold some message? why not just have msg= one or the other message?

Comment: Bro I'm learning javascript. In that concept var declared within the {} can be accessed outside with `undefined` value.I tried to execute that concept. In above example i want to know that why `imsg` print that msg outside the {} block.

Comment: You've mixed up variable scope with hoisting. You get undefined only if you try to access the variable before a value has assigned to it. See [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function loadProfiles(usernames){
    if(usernames.length >= 3){
        var wmsg='This might take a while';
    }
    else{
        var imsg="Just a sec";
    }
    console.log(wmsg);
}
loadProfiles(['Dinesh','Saratha','Sundhararasu']);
```

Note the use of the "greater than or equal to" operator `>=` on line 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` returns `undefined` because the condition in the if statement is not satisfied so the variable `wmsg` doesn't get initialized to the `string` '**This might take a while**' but is rather set to the value `undefined`.

Comment: Bro when i try to print `imsg` it should print `just a sec` but why it gives me `undefined`.

Comment: According to the code you posted above, the if block gets executed when the array length is greater than 3, setting variable wmsg to 'This might take a while'. If the array length is not greater than 3, the if block gets ignore, leaving the variable wmsg as undefined and executing the else clause. The else clause gets executed when the array length is not greater than 3. When the else clause gets executed, the imsg variable gets set to the value "Just a sec".  Hope this helps